# Insertion Sort from Right to Left

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to learn Insertion Sort in Java but I have a problem. I learned the insertion sort in ascending order. Now, I need to do it in descending order but I have to start sorting the array from right to left.

```
public class Sorting {

public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {                            
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j - 1]); j--)
            swap(a, j, j - 1);
    }
}

private static void swap(Comparable[] a, int i, int j) { 
    Comparable t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}

private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {                                                   
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}
```

}

The code which is above sorts the array from left to right in ascending order(1,2,3,4,..).

I need to change it in descending order but sorts from right to left(5,4,3,2..).
I change the code and tried this:

```
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) { 
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = N-1; i>=0; i--) { 
        for (int j = i; j >= 1 && less(a[j-1], a[j]); j++)
            swap(a, j, j-1);
    }
}
```

I changed the sort method several times but I got errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, I also tested it, try out:

```
    public class InsertionSort {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Comparable[] a = new Comparable[]{5,6,12,1,3,15,4,0,9};
            sort(a);
            for (int i = 1 ; i < a.length; i++)
                assert a[i].compareTo(a[i-1]) >= 0;
            System.out.println("sort is correct");
        }

        public static void sort(Comparable[] a) { // Sort a[] into         increasing order.
            int N = a.length;
            for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) { // Insert a[i] among         a[i-1], a[i-2],a[i-3]... ..                               
                for (int j = i; j < N && less(a[j - 1], a[j]); j++)
                    exch(a, j, j - 1);
            }
        }

        private static void exch(Comparable[] a, int i, int j) { 
            Comparable t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }

                private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w)                 {                                                   
            return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. What does "assert" do?

Comment: assert is just for testing purpose, consumes some boolean term, and if it is false, the program crashes. It's used only, when in the program flow some condition has to be fulfit, to check, that the state of your program is in correct state.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same algorithm, just in the check, which is smaller, exchange the arguments for the method `less` such that: `less(a[j - 1], a[j])`. Then the smaller elemenets will be shifted to the right.

Comment: It works for starting sort from left to right. When I try to print, it is true. But as I said, I need to start sorting from right to left.

Comment: why do you need to start from right to left? If you want to sort descend (from greatest to the smallest one), you can also sort from left to right, just taking first the biggest elements.

Comment: anyway, if really want to do that, then

Comment: anyway, if really want to do that, then the sorted part is at the and. Therefore, your inner loop must look like `for (int j = a.length-1; j > i && less(a[j-1], a[j]); j--)`

Comment: It does not sort in descending, it puts numbers random  (1,5,2,8..).

Comment: then you somewhere didn't exchange the indices properly. See my class below.